# How to use Apache for short URLs?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, short-url, rewritemap

**What is this about?**

I recently stumbled upon the question if Apache can be used for generic shortlink generation?

**Why whould I prefer Apache over 3rd party software like yourls?**

Of course, there are other options than Apache for that, but let's assume that you are stuck with Apache and can't use any 3rd party software...for whatever reason.

**How to do it?**

Create a RewriteRule to match all your shortURLs to a target link.

```
RewriteMap shortlinks txt:/etc/apache2/shortlinks.txt
RewriteRule ^/short(.*) ${shortlinks:$1} [R=permanent,L]
```

where the shortlinks.txt file should look something like this:

```
1  /startPage
2  /index.php
3  https://google.com
4  /any/target/URL/you/want?even=with&parameters=nice
```

This allows me to call example.com/short4 to be rewrited to example.com/any/target/URL/you/want?even=with&parameters=nice which I consider to be pretty neat.

**How is this helpful?**

Consider you are generating this shortlinks.txt automatically, i.e. in Drupal, maybe even in several versions for different units, like short_crm short_finance etc... One rewrite for each division and you are good to go.

**And finally...**

This is obviously just a brief look on what you can do, but the possibilities are pretty much endless from here...**will update my original post in case of constructive criticism/suggestions or specific questions :)**